# Loop through div class tags in BeautifulSoup only gets the first result

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

So, usually what I do when I want to loop through all the elements on a webpage is just do something like:

```
for i in range(..):
     print(get_stuff[i])
```

But in this case the entire HTML is all in one element, and findAll only gets you the first one, so even if I do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req = requests.get(f"https://jisho.org/search/%23words%20%23n%20?page=1")

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

concepts = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"concepts"})

tango = concepts[0].findAll("div",{"class":"concept_light clearfix"})

for _ in tango:
    tango1 = tango[0].findAll("span",{"class":"text"})[0].text
    print(tango1)
```

I just get the output of the first result repeated. How do I loop through all the "concept_light clearfix" tags instead? I've looked at other answers for a similar question but I didn't understand the solutions (or how to apply them to my case) at all. Please explain simply, thank you.

Comment: it should be `for x in tango:  tango1 = x.blabla` instead you're just repeating x times the first one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    req = session.get("https://jisho.org/search/%23words%20%23n%20?page=1")
    req.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for concept in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "concepts"}):
        for tango in concept.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "concept_light clearfix"}):
            for span in tango.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "text"}):
                print(span.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all tags with `class="concept_light"` and then select the the `<span class="text">` within this tag. For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get(f"https://jisho.org/search/%23words%20%23n%20?page=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

for concept in soup.select(".concept_light"):
    print(concept.select_one("span.text").get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
学校
川
手
戸
眼鏡
煙草
赤
仕事
英語
問題
部屋
子供
時間
雨
先生
年
手紙
電話
水
病気
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

The issue is in the `for-loop`. You are looping correctly, but using only the first item of `tango`. This:

```
tango1 = tango[0].findAll("span",{"class":"text"})[0].text
```

The `for-loop` should be like this:

```py
for i in tango:
    tango1 = i.findAll("span",{"class":"text"})[0].text.strip()
    print(tango1)
```

Output with the above for-loop.

```
学校
川
手
戸
眼鏡
煙草
赤
仕事
英語
問題
部屋
子供
時間
雨
先生
年
手紙
電話
水
病気
```